# Get href value of itemprop with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get all the `href` values having `itemprop="url"`, inside `main` div

HTML :

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="list_item odd" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello1" itemprop="url"> Hello 1</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list_item even" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello2" itemprop="url"> Hello 2</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery :

```js
$(('meta[itemprop="url"]'), '#main').each(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log (url);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the 'meta` part in your selector.

```js
$(('[itemprop="url"]'), '#main').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            console.log (url);
        });
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="list_item odd" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello1" itemprop="url"> Hello 1</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list_item even" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello2" itemprop="url"> Hello 2</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector like this `$('#main').find('a[itemprop="url"]')` .

1. [`find ()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjy9KTtmOPVAhUHMo8KHfPIB7EQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffind%2F&usg=AFQjCNG-8t8FlAFURjmRfahbB_JtshKgfg) target the `innerElement` of main .Apply the attr selector with `itemprop="url"`
2. No need to add `meta` with in a selector

```js
$('#main').find('a[itemprop="url"]').each(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="list_item odd" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
    <div class="overview-top">
      <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello1" itemprop="url"> Hello 1</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list_item even" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
    <div class="overview-top">
      <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello2" itemprop="url"> Hello 2</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `overview-top` class as a JQuery selector and then the attribute selector as `[itemprop="url"]` inside the `find`

```js
$('.overview-top').find('[itemprop="url"]').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log (url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class="list_item odd" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello1" itemprop="url"> Hello 1</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list_item even" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello2" itemprop="url"> Hello 2</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com/1" class="link">Example</a>
<a href="http://example.com/2" class="link">Example</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  const array = [];
  $('.link').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).attr('href');
  });
});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9fg6bb85/1/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can't find element `meta` with attribute `itemprop` so your example not working. You can search for any element that has attribute `itemprop` as in my example... or instead of `meta` set `a` element which will find only link elements

```js
$(function(){
  $('[itemprop="url"]', '#main').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class="list_item odd" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello1" itemprop="url"> Hello 1</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list_item even" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
        <div class="overview-top">
            <h4 itemprop="name"><a href="example.com/hello2" itemprop="url"> Hello 2</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```